# How to Restart an AsyncTask from inside onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to show Reload button on Dialoag box if the onPostExecute can not load data from server. So how can I restart or do something like that in AsyncTask?

Answer (score 3):

just call it again:

```
new mAsyncTask.execute("");
```

in some if block of **onPostExecute** when data is not loaded succesfully.

Comment: Will it not become recursive ?
Also, We already have the code of the AsynTask loaded in memory.
any way we can call the same code again ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your onClickListener of your Button:

```
if(task.cancel(true)) {
    YourTask task = new YourTask(this);
    task.execute();
}
```

So on button click you will try to cancel the current executed task and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

To restart your AsyncTask you need to create new instance of your asynctask and call execute();

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Response result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    new YourAsyncTask().execute();          
    }
}
```