# Reset AsyncTask to multiple execution

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-room

Is there any way to use `AsyncTask.execute()` multiple times?

Im using `AsyncTask` to check, if `User` exist in my Room Database.

My **`Login.class`** looks like this:

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> {

public Login(Context context, LoginListener listener){
    db = ApplicationDatabase.getDatabase(context); //i get Room here
    this.context = context; //context of app
    this.listener = listener; //my interfece for observe Boolean, works ok
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... body){
    try {
        user = db.userDao().getUser(body[0], body[1]);
        if (user != null)
            return Boolean.TRUE; //we find user with credentials
        else {
            return Boolean.FALSE; //we not find user with that credentials (from body)
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    listener.onLoginPerformed(result); //Boolen to activity
    selfRestart(); //i want to restart task here
}

private void selfRestart(){
    //maybe something to do here? its my own method
}

private ApplicationDatabase db;
private User user;
private LoginListener listener;
private Context context;
```

I call Task in this way (my **`Activity.class`**):

```
login = new Login(getApplicationContext(), this); 
//this is an interface that i implements in Activity definition

loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //execute() here, i cuted some not necesery code from here
            try {
                // im using get because i want to get valu from AsyncTask
                login.execute(email, password).get();
            }
            catch(Exception e){ }
}
```

I Read, that we can reset `AsyncTask` by making new `AsyncTask` (`Task = new Login()`) [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740369/how-to-restart-an-asynctask-from-inside-onpostexecute) but it dont work for me. When i try to make something like this in my `Login` class:

```
private void selfRestart(){
    Login task = new Login(context, listener);
    task.execute("");
    //im calling it in onPostExecute()
}
```

My android app crashes. My question is, what is the best way to reset `AsyncTask` that is implemented in diffrent file then my `Activity` class? Or maybe there is better way to make `Login` activity than implemented whole logic for login in `AsyncTask`?

**EDIT:**

Logcat:

```
2019-01-24 15:45:31.407 1048-1048/com.example.admin.keystroke_dynamics E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.admin.keystroke_dynamics, PID: 1048
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.admin.keystroke_dynamics.Activities.LoginActivity.onLoginPerformed(LoginActivity.java:62)
    at com.example.admin.keystroke_dynamics.Login.onPostExecute(Login.java:38)
    at com.example.admin.keystroke_dynamics.Login.onPostExecute(Login.java:14)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:692)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:709)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: "My android app crashes" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with  your crash. "Or maybe there is better way to make Login activity than implemented whole logic for login in AsyncTask?" -- have Room return a `LiveData` that your activity observes, and you should no longer need an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I updated my post with exception that i get from `logcat`. Im working in C# Stack. When i making my Room Database i based on Google's `CodeLabs` example. I dont see needed of `LiveData` to check user credentials. If `LiveData` is better, can you show some example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say,

> I call `Task` in this way (my `Activity.class`):
>
> ```
> login = new Login(getApplicationContext(), this); 
> //this is an interface that i implements in Activity definition
>
> loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v){
>             //execute() here, i cuted some not necesery code from here
>             try {
>                 // im using get because i want to get valu from AsyncTask
>                 login.execute(email, password).get();
>             }
>             catch(Exception e){ }
> }
> ```

, but no, you are *not* "calling" your task that way.  You are creating a single instance of the task, and setting up an event handler that executes that task -- that specific instance -- whenever the `loginButton` is clicked.  Since each `AsyncTask` instance may be executed only once, that will fail the second time the login button is clicked (if not sooner, for some other reason).

You also say,

> I Read, that we can reset AsyncTask by making new `AsyncTask` (`Task = new Login()`)

, but *no*, that does not reset anything, and indeed `AsyncTask` objects cannot be reset.  The advice you read was to *replace* the used `AsyncTask` with a fresh instance.  Instantiating a new `AsyncTask` has no particular effect on others.  If you want to pursue that approach then it might look something like this:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Login myLoginTask = login; // keep a reference to the current task
            login = new Login(... arguments ...); // create a new task for the next click

            try {
                // use the original task
                myLoginTask.execute(email, password).get();
            }
            catch(Exception e){ }
}
```

That specific implementation requires `login` to be non-`final`, so probably an instance variable of the containing class, not a local variable of the method from which your code was excerpted.

**HOWEVER**, your best way forward might very well be to ditch `AsyncTask` altogether.  When you use it like this:

> ```
>                 login.execute(email, password).get();
> ```

... you defeat the entire purpose.  You are making the thread in which that runs block until the task completes (that's what `AsyncTask::get` is *for*), so the task is effectively synchronous.  If that's what you require then you should just do the wanted work more directly instead of wrapping it up in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Your answer explain a lot, thanks!

But there is a problem. I can call `Context` of my app outside `buttonClick`, but i cant get `this` that is implemented interface of my `Activity` class. What im talking about, is this `this` statement: `login = new Login(context, this);`  when `this` is implemented observer into activity to catch changes on `onPostExecute()` in my AsyncTask

Comment: Can i make an Constructor for `Login` AsyncTask that take `Login` object and replace it?

Comment: Then i could use: `login = new Login(context, this)` ... here button click, then .... `Login newTask = new Login(login);? Because i have a problem with interface taht i implements and context (i can simply call context from outside of button click, but i cant get `this` as an interface)

Comment: @michasaucer, you can make a constructor for `Login` that reads needed details from another `Login` instance, but the constructor itself cannot replace references to the original instance with references to the new instance.  That's a job for the code that invokes the constructor.